# R: Import %||% null default operator from purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, r-package

I am building an R package and having trouble importing the `null-default` (`%||%`) operator from `purrr`.  Has anyone had success?  I've tried many different methods, but I can't find anything that works AND does not throw errors or warnings in `devtools::check()`.

I am using `roxygen2` to create the documentation.  Here's the current `roxygen2` comments.

```
#' Default value for `NULL`.
#'
#' @name %||%
#' @export
#' @importFrom purrr %||%
NULL
```

With this file, I get the warning below from `devtools::check()`
`\name should not contain !, | or @`

Any advice would be MUCH appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Why not re-create the function? It's straightforward: `function (x, y) 
{
    if (is.null(x)) {
        y
    }
    else {
        x
    }
}`

Comment: Do you know of any packages that import an operator with a similar name? If so, dig around in their source code. The only place I could think to look was `purrrlyr`, which has combo functions for `purrr` and `dplyr`. Rather than importing this operator, they just redefine it in a utilities file: https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr/blob/master/R/utils.R

Comment: You really don't want a `purrr` dependency just for that operator. Copy the source as suggested or use [`freebase`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/freebase).

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and advice!  

@Phil  I had implemented this solution. But when you load my package alongside `purrr`, you get a note that `%||%` has been masked. Whenever I see these messages, I don't take it for granted that they are the same.    
  
@camille that's great, I'll do some searching and I'll post again if I find a solution that has been previously and successfully implemented.

@hrbrmstr thank you, I've been meaning to look into `freebase`, and this is the perfect excuse!  I use a bunch of other `purrr` functions, so the dependency wouldn't only be for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, in the end, I omitted the export of `%||%`....it wasn't necessary and that is where the error was arising.  Here's the final version of the code I used.

```
#' Default value for `NULL`.
#'
#' @name null-default
#' @aliases %||%
#' @importFrom purrr %||%
NULL
```